# How do I define a case class that can accept both List[List[String]] and List[List[Int]] as inputs?

Tags: scala

I'm actually trying to make a class that can represent tabular data in columns. This is a simplified model of the code I'm working on intended to illustrate what's puzzling me about scala types.

Let's say I have two types

```
case class FunnyColumn[T](data:List[T])
case class FunnyTable(items:List[FunnyColumn[Any]])
```

I want to start adding stuff to my FunnyTable, so here goes. I make a bunch of columns that I might want to add:

```
val intItem:FunnyColumn[Int] = new FunnyColumn(List(1,2,3))
val stringItem:FunnyColumn[String] = new FunnyColumn(List("A", "B", "C"))
val untypedItem:FunnyColumn[Any] = new FunnyColumn(List(1,2,3))
```

So far so good:

```
// works but seems icky, untyped FunnyColumns are not much use to me!
val funny0 = new FunnyTable(List(untypedItem))
```

I don't really want my columns to be untyped - I want all of my columns to have meaningful types. In this example I've tried (and failed) to add a FunnyColumn[String]:

```
// Fails because it wants List[FunnyColumn[Any]] but I gave it List[FunnyColumn[Int]]
val funny1 = new FunnyTable(List(intItem))
```

The problem seems to be because I've defined FunnyTable as accepting literally `List[FunnyColumn[Any]]`, so anything other than a list of `Any` typed FunnyColumns is bound to fail.

What I want to do is is make it so that I can put any of the variations of FunnyColumn into my FunnyTable, in other words this should also work:

```
// Fails because it wants List[FunnyColumn[Any]] but I gave it List[FunnyColumn[_ :> String with Int]]
val funny2 = new FunnyTable(List(intItem, stringItem))
```

How can I redefine my FunnyTable class so that I can store different sub-types of FunnyColumn in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `FunnyColumn` covariant in `T`:

```
case class FunnyColumn[+T](data:List[T])
```

then `FunnyColumn[Any]` is a supertype of `FunnyColumn[Int]`.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Is there some reference material I can check out to explain how this powerful magic actually worked?

Comment: @SalimFadhley - You might find this [scala school](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#variance) page helpful. Basically, for some generic type constructor `F`, `F[A]` is not automatically a supertype of `F[B]` even if `A` is a supertype of `B`. The covariance annotation `+T`on `FunnyColumn` makes the relationship you want for columns.

Comment: "then FunnyColumn[Any] is a subtype of FunnyColumn[Int]" - surely you mean the opposite, FunnyColumn[Int] must be a sub-type of FunnyColumn[Any]?

Comment: @SalimFadhley - Yes sorry, I meant supertype.